# uniqueness of ID: single page or entire website?

Tags: html

Case study: I have a website with many archive pages. Every archive page contains a list of news and also a **"Load more"** link at the bottom of page to load more content by Ajax.

My exact question : Is the uniqueness of ID is bounded to a single page or entire  website? Should I write CSS,scripts etc. with the class of **"Load more"** button or its ID? I know both of ID and Class work programmatically but I am asking about the logical application of ID in software programming. Thanks.

Comment: IDs must be unique in the same document, not in the entire application/website. Don't worry about it, while your ids are unique in the same document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst it is true that it is unique to a given page - take care with this, since you may have a common external CSS sheet or javascript page that is inserted and utilised site wide. Therefore if you are not careful you may inadvertently apply styling or functionality to an element that is unintended - simply because it shares an id with another element on another page. Its  absolutely fine to have same id's on each page (and it may be that you want to have the same styling or function applied) - but it may not be that for all instances.

Answer (score 3):

> Is the uniqueness of ID is bounded to a single page or entire website?

A single page.

There is nothing wrong with having multiple pages wherein the same ID is assigned to the same element in every page that uses the same template. In fact, there is nothing wrong with taking that same ID and reassigning it to *some other element instead* in a specific page, or not assigning the ID within that specific page altogether.